# Define a new Type in Lean: Tensor power of vector space

Tags: lean, lean-mathlib, lean3

I want to define the tensor power of a vector space from the Lean library [mathlib](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib).

Here's the draft I have so far:

```
import data.complex.basic
import analysis.inner_product_space.basic
import linear_algebra.pi_tensor_product

open_locale tensor_product

notation ℋ`^⊗`n := ⨂[ℂ] i : fin n, ℋ

variables
(ℋ : Type) [inner_product_space ℂ ℋ]
(A : λ n : ℕ, ℋ^⊗n)
```

Any pointers are appreciated!

Comment: I have an open PR that adds these, [mathlib#14196](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib/pull/14196)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of about two hours after you asked this question, this exists in mathlib as [`tensor_power`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/find/tensor_power), with notation `⨂[ℂ]^n ℋ` for the example you mention.

If you're also interested in [`tensor_algebra`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/find/tensor_algebra)s, there is another open PR of mine, [mathlib#10255](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib/pull/10255), which provides the result `tensor_algebra R M ≃ₐ[R] (⨁ n, ⨂[R]^n M)`. I imagine this won't be merged for some time, as there are various technical issues to be resolved first.